# How do write an R script to access the AWS CLI?

Tags: r, amazon-s3, command-line-interface, aws-cli

Can someone show me (or tell me if it's possible) how to write the following AWS CLI command in R?

This command simply downloads the files to my local drive and I'd like to run it through R instead of using the command prompt.

aws s3 cp s3://mybucket/myfolder . --recursive

I tried using the shell() function, shell(cmd = 'aws s3 cp s3://mybucket/myfolder . --recursive'), but I get an error (execution failed with error code 1)

Comment: It seems like it ran but your aws cli command failed. Try intern=TRUE parameter setting in order to capture the output into an R variable.

Comment: Now I get "fatal error: Unable to locate credentials" but when I type in AWS configure into the CLI they are correct. Do I need to store them in another place?

Comment: Are your credentials stored in the default location? If not, you may need to check your environment variables with system("env", intern=TRUE).